# google analytics not recording 33% of results

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Hi I have a website running google analytics and the results it is recording are very inaccurate. I am recording an event in google analytics and recording the same event in a database so the count should match. I am finding that google analytics is not recording around 1/3 of the results. I know that some things can affect it such as people disabling javascript and cookies but surely that can't be 1/3 of people. Also I am only talking about less then 100 hits per day so GA shouldn't be sampling the data. Any comments would be appreciated.

EDIT: If you have compared your google analytics results to the results of your own database I would be interested in your results.

EDIT: In all my tests the results have matched perfect, Its the users results that seem to be wrong.

EDIT: <strike>Found the problem, I have ssl configured on the server and I was linking to the non ssl google analytics url. Since different browsers handle this sort of thing differently i was getting mixed results.</strike>
I'm still having the issue

Comment: Are you sure you aren't manually logging the event in your database 3 times per event? Sometimes I do that to make myself feel better about my applications.

Comment: No I have checked this many times. BTW I worded the question wrong. I meant 30% not being recorded.

Comment: Does this change after the data is 24 - 48 hours old?

Comment: No the issue is the same even when checking old data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was caused by a third party cookie issue. This is because my app is a third party app running on another site(similar to facebook apps) and anyone with 3rd party cookies disabled wont be recorded. issue fixed by not using cookies for google analytics.